# How to synchronize three producers and one consumer threads in java

Tags: java

I have to make three producers and one consumer thread. Producers threads is reading chars from file and using buffer of one char. I made Store like above, now i have to synchronize threads to consumer write whole word and give back control to other producer - patern like this

```
Producer1->Word1 
Producer2->word1 
Producer3->word1 
Producer1->Word2 
Producer2->word2 
Producer3->word2 
Producer1->Word3 
Producer2->word3 
Producer3->word3
```

Store (edited):

```
public class Store {
    public static final char CONSUMER_FREE = '\0';

    private volatile char consumer = CONSUMER_FREE;
    private final ThreadPoolExecutor executor;


    public Store(ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public synchronized void produce(char c) {
        while (isConsumerBussy()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        consumer = c;
        notify(); // single Consumer
    }

    public synchronized char consume() throws StoreProducersRip {
        while (isConsumerFree()) {
            try {
                wait(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            return consumer;
        } finally {
            freeConsumer();
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    private void freeConsumer() {
        consumer = CONSUMER_FREE;
    }

    private boolean isConsumerBussy() {
        return consumer != CONSUMER_FREE;
    }

    private boolean isConsumerFree() throws StoreProducersRip {
        if (executor.getActiveCount() == 0) throw new StoreProducersRip();
        return consumer == CONSUMER_FREE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic is flipped. The first thing that needs to happen for anything to 'go' is for one of the produces to produce a character, however, `produce()` loops __forever__ as long as `CONSUMER_FREE` is `\0`, which it is, and hence that'll never change. produce should loop while isConsumerBusy, and consume should wait until isConsumerFree.

Comment: @rzwitserloot you meen smth like this? (edited post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use locks for this purpose. Below code demonstrates 3 producer synchronous and 1 consumer async to producers but it'd also be sync to multiple consumers here. Also you should add some logic to consume same amount that produced. If you want to get benefits of multithreading, you should buffer your producer input and create some pipeline before consuming.

```java
public class Executor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Store store = new Store(executor);

        Runnable word1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                store.producerLock.lock();
                store.produce('1');
                store.produce('2');
                store.produce('3');
                store.producerLock.unlock();
            }
        };

        Runnable consume = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               store.consumerLock.lock();
               System.out.print(store.consume());
               System.out.print(store.consume());
               System.out.print(store.consume());
               System.out.println();
               store.consumerLock.unlock();
            }
        };

        Future p1 = executor.submit(word1);
        Future p2 = executor.submit(word1);
        Future p3 = executor.submit(word1);

        executor.submit(consume);
        executor.submit(consume);
        executor.submit(consume);

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you use a try/catch approach when using locks. Because now you are at risk of not unlocking when there is an exception.